# How can I configure the htaccess file in silverstripe on docker?

Tags: php, docker, .htaccess, silverstripe

I have a project based on the SilverStripe framework and I want to move it on docker, but after the docker configuration, it has some problem with loading the project from `public` folder. It works fine without docker on my local wamp but after moving on docker, it's not able to recognize my friendly URL. e.g `http://localhost:8080/admin`

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
ENV DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/html/public
    
COPY . $DOCUMENT_ROOT
WORKDIR $DOCUMENT_ROOT

COPY --from=composer:2 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock
#RUN composer install --no-dev
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf &&\
    a2enmod rewrite &&\
    service apache2 restart
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
RUN apt-get install -y libicu-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-configure intl && docker-php-ext-install intl
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    image: backend
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 8080:80
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD:
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 1280M
      MEMORY_LIMIT: 1280M
      MAX_EXECUTION_TIME: 600
    ports:
      - 8089:80
volumes:
  db-data:
```

`.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, I've found the below `.htaccess` file to fix the problem:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html /example.php
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.+) public/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```